# Understanding TypeScript pattern with MSSQL

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-mssql

I've recently been given this Node.js + TypeScript project and I'm trying to understand why the original author (not available to answer this question) uses a particular *pattern* to create a  [database connection pool with node-mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#connection-pools).

Basically, the suggested way to create a connection pool and a connection is (from the official docs)

```
// async/await style:
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
const poolConnect = pool.connect();

pool.on('error', err => {
    // ... error handler
});

await poolConnect;
```

This way the `pool` variable is declared and assigned directly as the result of `new sql.ConnectionPool(...)`, which then allows to call `pool.close()` at the end of the application, which is suggested

> [...] for example, if we are running some kind of CLI tool or a CRON job.

However the author of my code does

```
let pool: {
  connect: () => any;
  on: (arg0: string, arg1: (err: any) => void) => void;
  request: () => any;
};
let poolConnect: any;

// then after
pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
poolConnect = pool.connect();

// rest is the same
...
```

It is like *restricting* the pool variable to have only a subset of its potential methods (I cannot call `pool.close()` with a pool created this way for example), but I can't understand why would this be a good idea.

**Note**:
I am pretty confident it has nothing to do with MSSQL or database connection in particular and has more to do with Typescript in general, however I can't think of a good use case for this pattern, what am I missing?

Comment: I could speculate they were trying to control side effects created by other developers by limiting what was returned OR it could be the typing of that method was bad at some point and so they had to define a type based on observation or documentation.

Comment: @DanielGimenez Thank you. I think your second guess may be a good speculation, since the MSSQL library is written in js so it does not have typings. Maybe it' s a way to enforce typing? I've just found that there is a thing called `@types/mssql` (which the project **does not** use but still works) that should provide such typings, is it standard to include it in a Typescript project that uses MSSQL? Should it be done for every other js library that I add?